# How to call a function in Symfony 1.x using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony-1.4

I have a button in which onClick I want to call a function which is written in my Action file using Ajax. But I am not able to do this. I have the view file named as exportDataSuccess and the action file for this is exportDataAction. I have created function named as executeDownloadFile in exportDataAction which is to be called on click of the button. Below is my code. The other two functions in Action file are execute and preexecute. The module name is birthPublicSearch.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#downloadFile').click(function(){
    var urlAjax = '<?php echo URL_AJAX; ?>';

// urlAjax gives http://localhost:8080/crs/web/index.php

        $.ajax({
            url: urlAjax + "/birthPublicSearch/exportData/DownloadFile/",
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(response){  
                //console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });  
});
```

```
<tr>
   <td colspan="2" align="center" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
      <input type="button" id="downloadFile" name="downloadFile" value="Download File" class="btn"></input>
   </td>
</tr>
```

And the function is as

```
public function executeDownloadFile(sfWebRequest $request) {
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">
   alert("Test");
 </script>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a template for AJAX calls if you don't want one - try adding:

```
return sfView::NONE;
```

at the end of your PHP action code.

Also, try visiting the ajax URL in your browser to make sure the action is actually set up correctly (view source, as it won't show up on the page). You need to determine whether the PHP or the JS is at fault.

Not sure whether your input is inside a form or not, but probably good practice to prevent default behaviour inside your Javascript as well:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#downloadFile').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // The rest of your code here
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The above problem was solved, hope this will help others in future.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#downloadFile').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var urlAjax = "<?php echo URL_AJAX . '/birthPublicSearch' ?>";
   //urlAjax gives http://localhost:8080/crs/web/index.php/birthPublicSearch
        $.ajax({
            url: urlAjax + "/DownloadFile",
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(response){
            }
        });
    });  
});
```

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
      <input type="button" id="downloadFile" name="downloadFile" value="Download File" class="btn"></input>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And then create the executeDownloadFile function in the actions.class.php and perform whatever task you want in it and return sfView::NONE; at end of code.